# Append some text to multiple files in a directory

Tags: dired

I want to append some text to multiple files in a directory. So, I opened the directory in `dired` buffer and selected the files.

After this, is there any shortcut/ command to append some text to these files? There is a command `append-to-file` but that does not seem to serve my purpose.

Is there any other better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute shell commands from `dired`, so if you have your additional text in a file named `text`, you can mark all the files you want to append to with `m` and then do `! cat text >> ?` : the `?` gets replaced with each marked filename in turn.

Do `C-h f dired-do-shell-command` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other better way of doing this?

Programmatically, you could define custom functions:

```lisp
(defun my/append-file (text file)
  "Append TEXT to the end of a given FILE."
  (save-excursion
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file file)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "\n" text)
      (write-file file))))

(defun my/append-multiple-files (text files)
  "Append TEXT of the end of multiple FILES."
  (dolist (file files)
    (my/append-file text file)))
```

Then you can simply execute:

```lisp
(my/append-multiple-files "Emacs" '("~/foo.txt" "~/bar.txt"))
```

to add the text "Emacs" at the end of both files `~/foo.txt`, `~/bar.txt`. You can of course make this function interactive for a greater ease of use.

As concerns dired: once some files are marked in the dired buffer, you could simply execute in the minibuffer with `M-:` the following instruction:

```
(my/append-multiple-files "My text" (dired-get-marked-files))
```

There might be a more elegant way however...

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you can act on the marked files in arbitrary ways.

These keys/commands are available, for applying a function to the files, invoking a command in the files, or evaluating a sexp in the files. Each returns a list of the results.

- **`@ @`** -- `diredp-do-apply-to-marked`: Apply `FUNCTION` to the absolute name of each marked file.
- **`@ M-:`** -- `diredp-do-eval-in-marked`: Evaluate an Emacs-Lisp `SEXP` in each marked file.
- **`@ M-x`** -- `diredp-do-command-in-marked`: Invoke Emacs `COMMAND` in each marked file.

So if you wanted to, say, append `XXXXXXXXXXX` to the content of each of the marked files then you could do any of the following:

- Use `@ @`, and at the prompt for the function to apply to each marked file enter `toto`, after defining a function `toto` such as this:

```lisp
(defun toto (file)
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert "XXXXXXXXXXX")))
```

- Use `@ M-:`, and at the prompt for the sexp to evaluate at the beginning of each marked file, enter a sexp such as this:

```lisp
(progn (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "XXXXXXXXXXX"))
```

- Use `@ M-x` and enter `foo` at the prompt for the command to invoke in each marked file, after defining a command `foo` such as this:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (insert "XXXXXXXXXXX"))
```

In addition, there are equivalent commands that act on a set of files determined **recursively**.  These commands bound to the same keys but on prefix key `M-+` (e.g. `M-+ @ @`).  They operate on all marked files in the current Dired buffer and on all those marked in any marked subdirs, and so on (recursively). That is, they act on all marked files *here and below*.

---

Here are the doc strings, for more info.

> **`diredp-do-apply-to-marked`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `dired+.el`.
>
> It is bound to `@ @`, `menu-bar operate diredp-do-apply-to-marked`,
> `menu-bar operate apply diredp-do-apply-to-marked`.
>
> `(diredp-do-apply-to-marked FUNCTION &optional ARG)`
>
> Apply `FUNCTION` to the absolute name of each marked file.
> Return a list of the results.
> You are prompted for `FUNCTION`.
>
> A prefix arg behaves according to the `ARG` argument of
> `dired-get-marked-files`.  In particular, `C-u C-u` operates on *all*
> files in the Dired buffer.
>
> If you use multiple `C-u` as prefix arg then many files might be acted
> on, and some of them might already be visited in modified buffers.  If
> the function you apply modifies file content, and you want to save any
> such buffers before using this command, then use `C-x s`
> first.
>
> The result returned for each file is logged by `dired-log`.  Use `?`
> to see all such results and any error messages.  If there are fewer
> marked files than `diredp-do-report-echo-limit` then each result is
> also echoed momentarily.

---

> **`diredp-do-eval-in-marked`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `dired+.el`.
>
> It is bound to `@ M-:`, `menu-bar operate diredp-do-eval-in-marked`,
> `menu-bar operate apply diredp-do-eval-in-marked`.
>
> `(diredp-do-eval-in-marked SEXP &optional ARG)`
>
> Evaluate an Emacs-Lisp `SEXP` in each marked file.
>
> Visit each marked file at its beginning, then evaluate `SEXP`.
> Return a list of the results.
> You are prompted for the `SEXP`.
>
> The result returned for each file is logged by `dired-log`.  Use `?`
> to see all such results and any error messages.  If there are fewer
> marked files than `diredp-do-report-echo-limit` then each result is
> also echoed momentarily.
>
> A prefix argument behaves according to the `ARG` argument of
> `dired-get-marked-files`.  In particular, `C-u C-u` operates on *all*
> files in the Dired buffer.

---

> **`diredp-do-command-in-marked`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function
> in `dired+.el`.
>
> `(diredp-do-command-in-marked COMMAND &optional ARG)`
>
> Invoke Emacs `COMMAND` in each marked file.
>
> Visit each marked file at its beginning, then invoke `COMMAND`.
> You are prompted for the `COMMAND`.
>
> Only *explicitly* marked files are used.  A prefix arg has no effect on
> which files are used.
>
> A prefix arg is passed to `COMMAND` as its prefix arg.  For example, if
> `COMMAND` uses a numeric prefix arg `N` for repetition then the effect of
> `COMMAND` is repeated `N` times.
>
> Other than the prefix arg, no arguments are passed to `COMMAND`.
>
> If any of the marked files are already visited in modified buffers
> then you are prompted to save them first.
>
> If after invoking `COMMAND` in all of the marked files new buffers have
> been created to visit some of them then you are prompted to kill those
> buffers.
>
> An errors are logged by `dired-log`.  Use `?`  to see the error
> messages.
>
> Be aware that `COMMAND` could be invoked in a directory (Dired) buffer.
> You may not want to do this if `COMMAND` modifies the buffer text.
> (But generally this will have little lasting effect - you can just
> use `g` in that buffer to revert the listing.)